# SQL Natural Join

Tags: postgresql

Okay. So the question that I got asked by the teacher was this:

> 5. (5 marks) Construct a SQL query on the dvdrental database that uses a natural join of two or more tables and an additional where condition. (E.g. find the titles of films rented by a particular customer.)  Note the hints on the course news page if your query returns nothing.

Here is the layout of the database im working with: 
http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/PostgreSQL-Sample-Database.png

The hint to us was this:

> PostgreSQL hint:
>   If a natural join doesn't produce any results in the dvdrental DB, it is because many tables  have the last update: timestamp field, and thus the natural join tries to join on that field as well as the intended field.
>
> e.g.
>
> ```
> select * 
> from film natural join inventory;
> ```
>
> does not work because of this - it produces an empty table (no results).
>   Instead, use
>
> ```
> select * 
> from film, inventory
> where film.film_id = inventory.film_id;
> ```

This is what I did:

```
select * 
from film, customer
where film.film_id = customer.customer_id;
```

The problem is I cannot get a particular customer.
I tried doing `customer_id = 2;` but it returns a error.
Really need help!

Comment: Can you share your complete query and the error you get?

Comment: This is an excellent example on why `natural join` should be avoided like the plague.

Comment: The join condition `film.film_id = customer.customer_id` is completely wrong. A `film_id`  does not reference a `customer_id`. To get the films a customer rented you need to join film, inventory, rental and customer, e.g. `from film f  
join inventory i ON f.film_id = i.film_id 
   join rental r ON i.inventory_id = r.inventory_id 
   join customer c ON c.customer_id = r.customer_id`

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that you would like to join two tables that have no direct relation with each other, there's your issue:

```
where film.film_id = customer.customer_id
```

To find which films are rented by which customer you would have to join customer table with rental, then with inventory and finally with film.

The task description states

> Construct a SQL query on the dvdrental database that uses a natural join of **two or more tables** and an additional where condition.quote